# How to pack array of 8 bit unsigned integers into array of 11 bit unsigned integers

Tags: arrays, c, bit-manipulation

Imagine C provides unsigned integer type say uint11_t of size 11 bits.
I want to pack an array of 8-bit unsigned integers into array of 11-bit unsigned integers.

```
uint8_t in_array[100];    // 8 x 100 = 800 bits
uint11_t out_array[73];   // 11 x 73 = 803 bits enough to pack 800 bits from in_array
```

This is essentially sliding window problem where a window of 11 bits is to be slided on 8-bit words.

How can I do this using bit manipulation operations, array buffers and loops in C without relying on structures, unions or memcpy ?

Comment: there is nothing like uint11_t. You need at least 16 bits if you want to store 11 bits integer in the addressable output array.

Comment: @0___________ As strange as `uint11_t` is, it is possible for code declare as `typedef unsigned short uint11_t`. It is not a  reserved identifier.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `11 x 73 = 803 bits enough` ? Intersting. It invalidates your theory

Answer (score 0):

Read into an accumulator 8 bits at a time.
When 11 or more bits are in it, take 11 bits out and save.

The are different approaches if the repacking assume the lower address 8-bit bytes become the most or least significant  bits.  Below assumes they are least significant.

```
uint8_t in_array[100];
uint11_t out_array[73];

unsigned out_index = 0;
unsigned accumulator = 0;
unsigned bits = 0;
for (unsigned in_index = 0; in_index < 100; in_index++) {
  accumulator |= ((unsigned) in_array[in_index]) << bits;
  bits += 8;
  if (bits >= 11) {
    out_array[out_index++] = accumulator & 0x3FF;  // 11 LSBits
    accumulator >>= 11;
    bits -= 11;
  }
}
if (bits > 0) {
  // TBD code for OP
}
```

Comment: I thought that we should not be a free homework service. There is no OP effort, no code. In this form, the question should be closed and no answers given.

Comment: Thanks. I also solved it in another way. I will share the solution

Comment: @nurabha On Stack overflow, you can post [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to your own question.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to use at least uint16_t for this since there is no uint11_t in C. After that you'll need to calculate how many of those are required, in this case 50 (50X16 == 800).

```
uint8_t arr8[100];
uint16_t arr16[50];
uint16_t *ptr16 = (uint16_t *)arr8;
```

Then you can use the following :

```
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    arr16[i] = *ptr16;
    ptr16++;
}
```

Comment: It does not do what OP wants, and it in addition invokes undefined bahaviour

Comment: @0___________ : Can you please explain how it invokes undefined behaviour ?